# What is the correct DateTime format for MySQL Database?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, insert

I am Inserting this `DateTime` data `'12/21/2012 1:13:58 PM'` into my MySQL Database using this SQL string:

```
String Query = "INSERT INTO `restaurantdb`.`stocksdb` 
                  (`stock_ID`,`stock_dateUpdated`) 
                  VALUES ('@stockID' '@dateUpdated');
```

and I receive this error message:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '12/21/2012 1:13:58 PM' for column 'stock_dateUpdated' at row 1
```

So what is the right format/value for `dateTime` to input into a MySQL database?

Comment: change  VALUES ('@stockID' '@dateUpdated'); to  VALUES ('@stockID', '@dateUpdated'); and it should work

Comment: can u provide table sturucture or datatype for  "stock_dateUpdated" column

Comment: Comma missing in `VALUES`..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Q:** What is the right format/value for `DATETIME` literal within a MySQL statement?

**A:** In MySQL, the standard format for a `DATETIME` literal is:

```
 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'
```

with the time component as a 24 hour clock (i.e., the hours digits provided as a value between 00 and 23).

MySQL provides a builtin function `STR_TO_DATE` which can convert strings in various formats to `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes.

So, as an alternative, you can also specify the value of a `DATETIME` with a call to that function, like this:

```
STR_TO_DATE('12/21/2012 1:13:58 PM','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

So, you could have MySQL do the conversion for you in the `INSERT` statement, if your `VALUES` list looked like this:

```
... VALUES ('@stockID', STR_TO_DATE('@dateUpdated','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p');
```

(I notice you have a required comma missing between the two literals in your `VALUES` list.)

---

MySQL does allow some latitude in the delimiters between the parts of the `DATETIME` literal, so they are not strictly required.

[MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

Answer (score 2):

What I've used that works is year-month-day, with 24 hour time.  In PHP it's `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`, which I believe would correspond to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` in C#/.NET.  (The time part is optional, and so are the dashes.)

Confirmed in the docs, [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> Date and time values can be represented in several formats, such as quoted strings or as numbers, depending on the exact type of the value and other factors. For example, in contexts where MySQL expects a date, it interprets any of '2015-07-21', '20150721', and 20150721 as a date.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you are missing the delimiter `,` in the values. Also better to use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert string into date object first before inserting as:

```
String Query = "INSERT INTO `restaurantdb`.`stocksdb` "+
                " (`stock_ID`,`stock_dateUpdated`) VALUES "+
               "('@stockID', STR_TO_DATE(@dateUpdated, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'))";
```

Answer (score 0):

The MySql DATETIME format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS - See this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)