# One row returned sporadically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are no triggers on this table, though this tSQL script returns only one row, sporadically...  There is an index on LabNumber.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.MiniDataEntry
WHERE   LabNumber IN ( SELECT   labnumber
                       FROM     dbo.MiniDataEntry
                       WHERE    EnteredDate > '7/10/2015'
                       GROUP BY LabNumber
                       HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

I am attempting to determine if there are duplicate lab numbers today, there should not be.

Comment: What kind of data do you have in the table and how often is it changing?

Comment: Is the condition on `EnteredDate` always refer to `7/10/2015` or does it vary from day to day?

Comment: What you mean it returns 1 row sporadically? This is not the most efficient way to do this because you are hitting the same base table twice.

Comment: 7/10/2015 is not a valid date format, so you're comparing dates as STRINGS. `7/9/2015` will compare as LARGER than `7/10/2015`

Comment: Based on COUNT(*) > 1 that should never return one row.  You need to check for corruption of data (e.g. checktable).  Not the most efficient syntax but I seriously doubt this is a syntax problem.  Is the one row returned in fact a duplicate?

Comment: @Blam, no. I can run the tSQL above & it will return one row, then run it again (immediately) & it does not....

Comment: You need to get more specific or I am going to vote to close.  Is the one row correct or not?  When it does not return one row are the results correct of not?  Have you run checktable?

Comment: No, the one row is not correct.  In the sub query, I am looking where COUNT(*) >1, then when I use those results to query the table, it returns only one row.  I do not understand how that is possible. 

I cannot run checktable at this time, that will have to happen off hours.

Comment: Voting to close.   I ask specific questions trying to help and only get partial answers.

Comment: @Blam, thanks for you help & sorry I did not respond you your question as you feel I should have.  I thought I answered it with all the information you requested. In your earlier comment (Based on COUNT(*) > 1 that should never return one row), you are correct, it should not. The LabNumber field should be unique. If I execute the script 10 times, maybe once it will return one row & I know that is incorrect. I was hoping to get some insight from someone who may know what is causing only one row to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

One mistake in your query is the incorrect date formatting -

```
7/10/2015
```

is interpreted as a string -> you are not able to compare this 
string with other dates properly.

You should format your String as

> 2015-07-10

and it should be interpreted correctly.

The correct date format in sql is

> 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'

at the moment. (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984638/what-is-the-correct-datetime-format-for-mysql-database) for more information)

Comment: I changed the date to CONVERT(DATE,'7/10/2015') same results.

Comment: TSQL will convert that format try  select '7/10/2015', cast('7/10/2015' as datetime)  EnteredDate is a DataTime then the string value must be a valid datetime